# Bridging NSImage and UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have an iphone application that can be enriched with additional content downloadable in the form of `packages`.

This additional content (packages) is built using a MAC OS application.

The MAC OS application is used to gather resources and artwork, do the layout, and create the `package`.

Some of the package contains serialized objects (NSCoder), amongst which are NSImage objects.

My issue is : NSImage does not exist on iPhone.

Is it possible to deserialize an NSImage into an UIImage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert NSImage to NSData and then this NSData is to UIImage.
NOTE : Save image data to file to read from it

```
MAC CODE
NSData *imageData = [self.someImage TIFFRepresentation];

iOS CODE
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the images as `Data` (it is `Encodable`) on **macOS**, and then instantiate the `UIImage` on **iOS** by doing:

```swift
let image = UIImage(data: yourData) // yields UIImage?
```